# iText - Anchor at position

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I've this cose with iText 5

```
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("/Users/mac02/Desktop/AnchorDemo.pdf"));
            doc.open();
            String content = "Text: ";
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(content);
            // Creates a new anchor that link to external website
            // and add this anchor to the paragraph.
            Anchor anchor = new Anchor("Examples");
            anchor.setReference("https://www.google.it/");
            paragraph.add(anchor);
```

This write text at the top of the page of pdf. How can i write at a certain position of the page?

Thanks